# Banach space :space of all adapted processes continuous equipped wih specific norm is complete

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, banach-spaces, stochastic-analysis

Let  $\mathbb{B}$ be space of all adapted processes continuous equipped with 
    the norm $\lVert Y\rVert_{\mathbb{B}}^2=E\left[\sup_{t\in [0,T]} |Y_{t}|^{2}\right] < \infty $,
     $(B,\lVert\cdot\rVert_{\mathbb{B}})$ is complete ( is Banach space ).

Indeed, 
suppose $(X^{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in  $(\mathbb B,\lVert\cdot\rVert_{\mathbb{B}})$.  Then we can find a subsequence  $(n_{k})_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lVert X^{n_{k+1}}-X^{n_k}\rVert_{\mathbb B} &<\infty 
\mbox{ by the triangular inequality, }\\
 E\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sup_{t\geq  0}|X_{t}^{n_{k+1}}-X_{t}^{n_k}|^{2}]^{\frac{1}{2}}\right]  &\leq  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E\left[\sup_{t \geq 0}|X^{n_{k+1}}-X^{n_k}|^{2}\right]^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lVert X^{n_{k+1}}-X^{n_k}\rVert_{\mathbb{B}}<\infty\\
\mbox{Then }
E[ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sup_{t \geq 0}|X_{t}^{n_{k+1}}-X_{t}^{n_k}|^{2}]^{\frac{1}{2}} &<\infty
\end{align}
and so for almost every $\omega \in \Omega$ 
$$
 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sup_{t \geq 0}|X_{t}^{n_{k+1}}-X_{t}^{n_{k}}|<\infty
$$
then $(\mathbb{B},|.|_{\mathbb{\infty}})$ with $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{\infty}=\sup_{0\leq t \leq T }|X_{t}|$
then  $(B,\lVert\cdot\rVert_{\infty})$ is complete 
then there exists a
process $X\in \mathbb{B}$ such that $(X_{t}^{n_{k}}(\omega))_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$

$$ (X_{t}^{n_{k}}(\omega))_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \xrightarrow[n \longrightarrow  \infty]{C.U} X(\omega) \hspace{4mm} \forall t \geq 0$$
now:
\begin{align}
|X^{n}-X|_{\mathbb{B}}^{2}&=E[\sup_{t \geq 0}|X_{t}^{n}-X_{t}|^{2}]\\
\text{by Fatou's lemma}
& \leq \lim_{k \to \infty} \inf E\left[ \sup_{t \leq 0}|X_{t}^{n}-X_{t}^{n_{k}}|^{2}\right]^{2}\\
&=\lim_{k \to \infty} \inf|X^{n}-X^{n_{k}}|_{\mathbb{B}}^{2}\xrightarrow[n \longrightarrow  \infty]{} 0
\end{align}
since  $(X^{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy sequence $(\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup |X^{n}-X^{n_{k}}|=0)$.

My question: Am i right? If not, please correct. 
Please respond. I'll be grateful for any help offered!

Comment: Just a question, but what about the adaptedness?